# Whats wrong with this grep command?

Tags: linux, bash

`rpm.txt`:

```
Augsburg\n
Bremen\n
Friedrichshafen\n
Aschersleben\n
Bernburg\n
Berlin\n
Halle\n
Essen\n
Furtwangen\n
Kehlen\n
Krumbach\n
Osnabrueck\n
Kempten\n
```

And my command:

```
cat rpm.txt | grep '[^a]'
```

This returns the text unchanged, although I have filtered, with grep, to all entries with `a`, why?

Comment: Just a small suggestion: you don't need to `cat` and pipe to `grep` like that, since `grep` can take input as a file: `grep '[^a]' rpm.txt` will work just as well, and with less overhead from starting cat and making the shell deal wtih the pipe. (I do the same thing a lot, but it's not the best habit to have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your command. To know why it doesn't work you first need to understand `regex` a little.

What you're basically doing is to `grep` everything that's not a lowercase `a`. That means that, if you would add the `-o` option, it will remove that character.

If you want to remove cities with a lower case `a`, you will have to restrict a line to contain an `a`. To do so, you will have to use the character `^` and `$` which are the beginning of the line and the end of a line respectively. Furthermore you will have to add `*` after `[^a]`, which means that the sequence of characters can contain 0..N characters (where N>=0), but not an `a`.

```
grep '^[^a]*$' rpm.txt
```

p.s.
You can make use of the option `--color=auto`. This will show which characters are "grepped" in red. Otherwise, try a site such as regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern [^a] in regex for what you are searching means the character set all character except the lowercase letter a.  When you search for that character set, you get any line that has any character in that character set.  You essentially searched for any line that has any character other than lower case a.
So if rpm.txt was as follows

```
a
aaaaaa
aaaa aaaa
aaaaaaaa1
Augsburg
```

your result would have been

```
aaaa aaaa
aaaaaaaa1
Augsburg
```

The first and second lines only have the character lower case a, the third line has a space, the fourth has a 1, and the last has no lower case a's.